# Javascript element with no id

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a client-side javascript function on an ASP.Net page that's giving me fits. It's supposed to loop through the rows of a gridview, and through the controls on each row. It's finding a dropdownlist called `ddlRole` as it should, but then `ddlRole` doesn't seem to have an id property. ?? Here's the code:

```
 var gridID = '<%= gvMultiTimekeepers.ClientID %>';
    gridview = document.getElementById(gridID);
    for (var i = 0, row; row = gridview.rows[i]; i++) {
        var controls = row.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (var j = 0; j < controls.length; j++) {
            var role = "";
            if (controls[j].id.indexOf("ddlRole") || controls[j].id.indexOf("ddlNewRole")) {
                alert("ddlRole id = " + controls[j].id);
                var ddlRole = controls[j];
                role = ddlRole.options[ddlRole.selectedIndex].value;
            }
        }
   }
```

So the code correctly finds the ddlRole using `controls[j].id.indexOf` but when the alert fires, it shows `controls[j].id` is blank. How is this possible? (I'm doing this alert because when I get to the assignment of the `role` variable two lines down, I'm getting an undefined or null reference error message.)

Comment: No idea. What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: You should be checking `indexOf()` against `>-1` as in: `if (controls[j].id.indexOf("ddlRole") > -1 || controls[j].id.indexOf("ddlNewRole") > -1)` since `-1` is  what `indexOf()` returns when no match is found. If the match is found at index `0`, your code will give you a false negative.

Comment: You might consider narrowing your search a bit more as well. For instance, using `row.querySelectorAll('select, input, textarea')` would get just the form elements in the row, rather than every possible element.

Comment: if `controls[j].id` = `''` or `[]` then `controls[j].id.indexOf("ddlRole")` will return `-1` which **does not** equal `false`

Comment: To follow up with what Scott Marcus said above, currently the `if` statement would return true because your target string was not found and `indexOf` would return `-1` when a string is not found. And essentially any number that is not `0` is considers a `true` value. The `indexOf` function returns the `index of` the first character from a string that another substring was found. `-1` is returned because it is not a valid index of the initial string which would fall between 0 (before first character) and string.length-1 (before last character).

Comment: `row.querySelectorAll("select[id^=ddlRole], select[id^=ddlNewRole]")` assuming that the id *starts with* ddlRole or ddlNewRole

Comment: @JonathanKuhn That's not quite accurate. When an `if` condition is presented with a number and a boolean to be compared, the boolean is converted to a number (not the number being converted to a boolean) and then compared against the other number, so `true` would be converted to `1` and then compared against `-1`. To test this, open your console and type `-1 == true`. You will get `false`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus however, `if(-1)console.log('test')` will log test. When doing a comparison, you are correct, however as a conditional by itself, it is true.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn But, that's not the situation here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus how so? OP is not comparing the return value from `indexOf` (`-1`) to true or anything else. They are just saying `if(-1 || -1)` where `-1` is the return from the function call. I was just trying to make it clear why their `if` statement was being treated as true.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn True (no punn intended). ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus - you're right. If you put your comment into an answer, I'll upvote it and mark it as *the* answer. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Melanie Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking `indexOf()` against `>-1` as in:

```
if (controls[j].id.indexOf("ddlRole") > -1 || controls[j].id.indexOf("ddlNewRole") > -1)
```

since `-1` is what `indexOf()` returns when no match is found.

In your scenario when the `id` isn't found, you are incorrectly entering the `true` branch of your `if` statement (a false positive) and if the match is found at index `0`, your code will give you a false negative since `0` converts to a "falsey" value.